# c++ second function from a Class doesn't have access to first one

Tags: c++, oop, matrix

My code stores integers in a [n] x [n] matrix. But when I use my printMatrix() method, it returns only zeros on command prompt, instead of integers I previously assigned to the matrix. I think I have to use reference/pointers but I'm not quite sure how. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Matrices
{
public:
    Matrices();
    void storeMatrix(vector <vector <int> > matr, int n);
    void printMatrix(vector <vector <int> > matr, int n);

private:
    int n;
    vector <vector <int> > matr;
    int cell;
};//class Matrices
Matrices::Matrices()
{

}//Constructor

void Matrices::storeMatrix(vector <vector <int> > matr, int n)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                cout << "Please insert an int for matr [" << i << "] [" << j << "]" << endl;
                cin >> cell;
                matr[i][j] = cell;
            }
        }


}//storeMatrix

void Matrices::printMatrix(vector <vector <int> > matr, int n)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                cout << matr[i][j];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
}//printMatrix


int main()
{
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    int n = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)  // loop to make the input integer equivalent to power of 2;
        n = n * 2;

    vector <vector <int> > matr (n , vector <int> (n));
    Matrices k;
    k.storeMatrix(matr, n);
    k.printMatrix(matr, n);


    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: You're right about needing references for `storeMatrix`. For `printMatrix` it should not be necessary, although a const ref may save on performance. Additionally, your design is a bit unclear. Should `printMatrix` print the stored matrix, or print any matrix passed in? Why does the function parameter have the same name as the class parameter?

Comment: printMatrix should print the matrix stored in storeMatrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the parameters related to `printMatrix()`. In main() and in its prototype(within the class) and from its definition `void YourClassName::printMatrix()`. and then inside its definition set this:

`cout << this->matr[i][j];` // see below for further explanation

instead of this:

`cout << matr[i][j];`

Adding `This` will print the private member of "*this current instance*" that you already filled with data in the previous function.

Also in your `store()` you need to "link" what you are doing with the current instance.

Overall: This design should help you understand better what is going on. See this main():

```
int main()
{
    int m;
    int n = 1;

    cin >> m;

    Matrices k(m, n); // create an object k
    k.storeMatrix(); // store matrix for "this" object k 
    k.printMatrix(); // print matrix of "this" object k 

    return 0;
}
```

And look at the class:

```
class Matrices
{
public:
    Matrices();
    Matrices(int, int);
    void storeMatrix();
    void printMatrix();

private:
    int n;
    vector <vector <int> > matr;
    int cell;
};//class Matrices

Matrices::Matrices() 
{}

Matrices::Matrices(int m, int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)  // loop to make the input integer equivalent to power of 2;
        n = n * 2;

    vector <vector <int> > _matr (n, vector <int>(n));
    this->matr = _matr;

}//Constructor

void Matrices::storeMatrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->matr.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->matr[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << "Please insert an int for matr [" << i << "] [" << j << "]" << endl;
            cin >> cell;
            this->matr[i][j] = cell; //whatever "this" object is, store its matrix
        }
    }
}//storeMatrix

void Matrices::printMatrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->matr.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->matr[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << this->matr[i][j]; // whatever "this" objecct is, print its matrix
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}//printMatrix
```

Comment: Who and why the down vote? Maybe I need to learn something that I am missing

Comment: Don't know about any down vote, but once you've correctly removed the `matr` argument to both functions, you don't need to also qualify `this->matr`.

Comment: @Useless Right. I will keep it just for the sake of explaining